# Prestashop, empty parameters for my personnal reference

Tags: python, api, web-services, reference, prestashop

I am developing a tool that communicates with API (Prestashop API) using Python. When I try to create an order with a product, everything seems to work fine, but the I want to put an personnal reference and I dont find any empty parameters. I have try to change id and reference but it dont want to change.
Details:
Order creation successful with the specified product Stock but need an empty parameters to put my reference

I have try to change id and reference but it dont want to change.
When I save the order, prestashop put their reference.

```
# This is the order parameters
orderJ = {
        'reference': 'test',
        'id_currency': 1,
        'id_carrier': 1,
        'id_lang': 1,
        'current_state': 'PS_OS_PAYMENT_ACCEPTED',
        'module': 'ps_checkpayment',
        'payment': 'ps_checkpayment',
        'total_paid': order["base_subtotal"],
        'total_paid_real': order["base_shipping_amount"],
        'total_products': order["base_shipping_incl_tax"],
        'total_products_wt': '13.120000',
        'conversion_rate': order["total_incl_tax"],
    }

    response = ord.createOrder(userJ, addressJ, billadressJ, cartJ, itemJ, orderJ)
    
I have try this too:

# Mise a jour de la reference
# ord = prestashop.get('orders', response['prestashop']['order']['id'])
# ordid = ord['order']['id']
# ord['order']['reference'] = 'test'
# edit = prestashop.edit('orders', ordid, ord)
# print(edit)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I do not really get which wrapper you are using,
if you communicate directly with the Prestashop API (webservices) via the XML / **order** resource, you have the option of defining a custom reference for each order row with the **<product_reference>** field within the various **<order_rows>**

You can find official documentation of the **order** resource [here](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/webservice/resources/orders/)

Comment: Thanks
I use the Api webservice (PrestaShopWebServiceDict), I use Json to send data. For the <product_reference>, it change for the product no for the order.
I need to identicate order with personnal reference. Its an order copy from another marketplace and I need to identicate it to prevent duplicate

Maybe Its impossible to change Order reference? I have try to use the "note" on order but I same thing, the note I put dont save in database.

Comment: Inside the order resource, reference is called "product_reference" so you'll need to edit that field.

Comment: I see, I go check it thanks